# Can't see HDRI in cycles/eevee in blender 2.8

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, hdri

I don't know what happen, I don't know if i just have a deactivated a node or an option.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender SE :). There might be multiple reasons, you can [upload your file here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so others can have a look.